# Use .gdsl file in a Java project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a file `pipeline.gdsl` that contains the Syntax for my Jenkins Pipeline DSL. Following [this blog post](http://st-g.de/2016/08/jenkins-pipeline-autocompletion-in-intellij) I put the file into the `/src` folder of my Java project. When I now edit my `Jenkinsfile` (residing in the root folder of my project), I don't get any code completion / syntax explanation as I would expect.

My project is a Java / Gradle project and I cannot make a Groovy project out of it. Is there some other way to make IntelliJ aware of the `.gdsl` file and provide code completion?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem was, that `/src` was not marked as a source root folder in my project. Creating a folder `/src/main/groovy`, putting the file in there and marking it as a sources root (right click on the folder -> Mark directory as -> Sources Root) did the trick.

Comment: How does one do this in Android studio? The Mark Directory As option seems to be issing.

Comment: Note: I also had to associate the Jenkinsfile as a Groovy file type using IntelliJ's preferences: http://imgur.com/a/EWATV

Comment: Do you get the warning `'node' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure<Object>)'`?

Comment: @lanoxx same problem here.

Comment: I found a solution for that warning. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47074631/474034

Comment: @bob-gregor did that help you?

Comment: when using maven and custom sources directory you can use:
`<build>
        <sourceDirectory>pipelines</sourceDirectory>
    </build>`
works for me with `pipeline.gdsl` file exported from Jenkins.

Comment: I have a setup similar to this.  The gdsl is loaded and we get auto completion.  However, if I make a change to the file and check it in, all developers must touch the file in order to load the new changes (if it is their first time getting the file, as when I introduced it), the have nothing until they touch the file.  Any ideas?  again - the directory is a "Sources Root"

Comment: This is not working for me, even with a simple project with just a pipeline.gdsl and a Jenkins file. 'node', 'ws' 'stage', etc ... are not resolved.
I have groovy installed on my computer, GROOVY_HOME exists, groovy path to bin is added to PATH, the folder is declared as source folder. However it is a groovy project, not a java one.