# Get autocomplete for shared pipeline groovy code?

Tags: intellij-idea, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have some shared pipeline groovy code in a scm repo. I'd like to be able to get auto complete of this groovy code in another intellij project (similar to how the pipeline.gdsl stuff works)

I can clone the project local and have access to the source files, is there any way to get intellij to pick up auto complete of these files?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062514/use-gdsl-file-in-a-java-project-in-intellij