# Jenkins pipeline in IntelliJ with GDSL. Warning: 'node' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.closure<Object>)'

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, groovy

I am using Jenkins with Pipelines and have defined a *scripted pipeline* using a `Jenkinsfile`. It looks something like this:

```
node {
  /* some stages */
}
```

I have imported the GDSL File that comes with Jenkins into IntelliJ. Now I got syntax highlighting but the whole file is being highlighted in a single warning block for which IntelliJ shows the following message:

```
'node' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.closure<Object>)'
```

I thought it might be that the node object is not supported as root by the syntax definition, but if i try to write `pipeline` as root then the same warning appears.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution. A small change is required in the `pipeline.gdsl` file (e.g. the GDSL file which was downloaded from Jenkins and placed into IntelliJ by us).

Find the following line in the gdsl file:

```
method(name: 'node', type: 'Object', 
       params: [label:java.lang.String, body:'Closure'], 
       doc: 'Allocate node')
```

And add this line in addition to the previous one:

```
method(name: 'node', type: 'Object', 
      params: [body:'Closure'], 
      doc: 'Allocate node')
```

This will create an overload definition in the Syntax tree that tells IntelliJ that the node method has two version one which accepts both a `String` and a `Closure`, and another which accepts only a `Closure`.

Comment: Tracking issue in Jenkins Jira: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39488

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. Then I found this post so I tried again...

I had to also restart Idea to update the gdsl.

Comment: Didn't work for me either

Answer (score 3):

To solve the same issue, but with `pipeline`:

> 'pipeline' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

Add:

```
method(name: 'pipeline', type: 'Object', params: [body:'Closure'], doc: 'Pipeline root element')
```

Comment: Adding similar lines also solved the problem for `parallel` and `input`.