# Jetbrains IDEA Jenkinsfile language/syntax support

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have been googling and messing around with Jetbrains IDEA for hours now, and I can't understand how to add this IDE support.

There was a way to add similar support for Java applications at one point.

How can I get keyword highlighting, and click through links to dsl/source-code support etc.

I've already set up the Jenkinsfile to be treated as groovy, but beyond formatting there's no other support, or intelligent insights.

ty!

Comment: There is a related request specifically for Jenkins file support: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158104

Comment: https://st-g.de/2016/08/jenkins-pipeline-autocompletion-in-intellij

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use .gdsl file in a Java project in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062514/use-gdsl-file-in-a-java-project-in-intellij)